# Testflight doesn't show "Update Profile" Option anymore

Tags: ios, testflight

I often had to change the provisioning profiles for my ios builds due to new testers/udids. 
I had no problems following this guide [Adding more testers to a build?](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829818-adding-more-testers-to-a-build-)
I updated my profile in the devcenter and made the upload, everything works perfect. But from today on I miss this option completely, the `Update Profile` Button and the complete row is just gone.

I googled changes regarding `testflight` but couldn't find anything.

Someone has a clue?

Answer (score 7):

iOS 8 doesn't support installing provisioning profiles individually any longer. So this doesn't work on iOS 8 devices any more and you have to create a new build using the updated profile to add new devices.

Comment: @kerni any pointers or documentation about the same thing will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no known documentation other than checking the settings app and comparing the menus and actually trying to install a profile and check what happens, including looking at the console output.

Answer (score 5):

I emailed TestFlight about that this morning and this was their response.  Looks like it's for iOS8 as others have pointed out :

"Due to the changes in iOS 8, it's no longer possible for testers to install provisioning profiles from the iOS Settings app. App developers will now need to rebuild their Ad Hoc beta apps to update the embedded provisioning profile in the app's IPA file. If you need any help with this process, please let us know.

You can also find more information about updating provisioning profiles from the link below:
http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829818"

Answer (score 2):

I was able to change a particular build's embedded provisioning profile manually. Here's how I did it.

1. Download the build's IPA file from the testflightapp website. You can download it by accessing the build's share address in your browser. That's the https://www.testflightapp.com/install/BUILD_ID link that's shown on the Build Permission page.
2. Change the ipa file's extension to zip and unzip the archive.
3. Right-click and Show Package Contents on the single file inside the Payload folder.
4. Replace the embedded.mobileprovision file with your updated provisioning profile.
5. Recreate the zip archive and change its extension to ipa.
6. Upload that ipa file to test flight.

Comment: This works for iOS 7 still, but please be aware that it will not work for iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

The option has dissappeared for me as well. I was also using the option frequently. 
However, I did notice problems and the feature was no longer working once the iOS 8 GM was released on iOS 8 devices. 
Even though I updated the profile, the build failed to install every time. (And now that you asked I noticed it's gone).
I also browsed through all the settings/permissions/etc, but it seems they removed the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Since Apple acquired TestFlight, they changed the whole process for iOS 8:

- No more provisionning profiles, only Apple ID's email.
- 1,000 beta testers and 25 internal testers per application.
- https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ is the new testflightapp.com/dashboard/

I have successfully replaced my old process following this one: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224

Comment: Is enterprise distribution not supported anymore? Can't see it mentioned anywhere (I know it worked(s) on old Testflight, but how about since Apple acquired it?)